# Using SDL2 for software development

Tags: c++, cross-platform, sdl-2, software-design

I was surfing the internet this morning and I came upon reading about SDL2 game programing library for c++.  Looking at how SDL2 works, I wonder if actual software applications can be developed with game programing libraries like SDL2. Why or why not would be really helpful for me to understand the reasons why you would ever do this. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Simple DirectMedia Layer is a cross-platform development library designed to provide **low level** access to audio, keyboard, mouse, joystick, and graphics hardware via OpenGL and Direct3D.

I put an emphasis on *low level*.

- Graphics: the only things you can do are drawing pixels or images / textures. You won't be able to use menus, buttons, etc. unless you code them, with can be a bit paintful.
- Mouse: you only have access to *events*, this means that you need to check yourself on which area was a click and monitor yourself if a button is still pressed
- Keyboard: same thing, you only know when a touch is pressed / released. Text inputs for example can be paintful.

A consequence of that is that the applications using it are those who don't care about menus, buttons, etc. and that need to have low-level access on the keyboard / mouse events: video games are a big part of it.

> It is used by video playback software, emulators, and popular games.

So, if by software development you mean something that can be as complicated as a notepad, forget about SDL! Qt, WxWidgets, GTK, etc. are your friends.

A counter-example might a scientific research program, in which you usually don't care much about ergonomics and sometimes prefer low-level access.

Comment: Very well and put and I think you! I also found, that SDL2 is good for touch event handling which can be a pain with other actual gui libraries. I hope that GTK+ picks up some better support for mobile devices soon, I read that they are working on it.

Answer (score 1):

First off, SDL2 is not a "game programming library", it's a multimedia library. But of course it can be used for game development.

> I wonder if actual software applications can be developed with [multimedia libraries] like SDL2.

Yes.

But if you're using C++, you'd want to use SFML instead of SDL, because SDL only has a C interface, which doesn't go together very well with modern C++.